# Do specific names give powers to the seraph blades?

Tags: shadowhunters

In the Shadowhunter books, we see them naming the seraph blades so that they may be used. Do these names give any special powers? Like, if they named one after Michael(I think they did once, but don't remember), is the blade more powerful since Michael is an Archangel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seraph Blades](http://shadowhunters.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph_blade) shows that the answer to your question is **yes**.

> Seraph blades are the primary weapons of the Shadowhunters. They are
>   made of adamas and crafted by the Iron Sisters. They call upon the
>   power of angels' names to access the power of the blades.
>
> Before the blade can be used, a Shadowhunter must name it to invoke
>   its power. Any angel's name, except for Raziel's, can be called upon.
>   Within the Shadowhunter community, it is often believed that when a
>   Shadowhunter names a seraph blade, the blade not only becomes engulfed
>   by heavenly fire, but some of the named angel's spirit is infused into
>   the blade as well.
>
> 2.0 2.1 2.2 The Shadowhunter's Codex (real)

According to that source, your recollection of Michael is correct.

> According to Shadowhunter legend in the earliest days of the Iron
>   Sisters, when they were few in number and their Adamant Citadel was no
>   more than a single adamas forge and a few protective wards, a lone
>   Iron Sister was confronted with a Dragon demon in the Citadel. In her
>   desperation, she picked up and pointed an unprocessed adamas jag at
>   the Dragon, and prayed to the Archangel Michael, making the adamas
>   unexpectedly burst to life as a sword. It bored through the Dragon's
>   neck, engulfing it in heavenly fire. She then deduced what had just
>   happened, and by the time her fellow sisters returned to the Citadel,
>   she had drawn up the first set of plans for the seraph blades

The power of the blade is dependant on the intensity of the invocation.

> Seraph blades are activated when their name is called. It is said to
>   be stronger the louder the angel's name is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in *The Shadowhunter's Codex* they say that some Iron Sister who named hers Michel made the Dragon she stabbed with it catch fire and died. I think naming one Raziel would make not only the blade, but also the Hunter using it, explode into flames.

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting your thinking here?